# How do I use RegEx to redirect non www to www with an exception for one SSL subdomain?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I am no means an expert on RegEx, but I have the following htaccess rule already in place on a site I am working on:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

How do I keep this rule, but add an exception that stops secure.domain.com from redirecting to www.secure.domain.com and also forces SSL on the secure.domain.com domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional `RewriteCond` directive to the above ruleset, to exclude the `secure` subdomain, the same way you are excluding the `www` subdomain. The `RewriteCond` directives are implicitly AND'd:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^secure\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In per-directory .htaccess files, you will need to add a slash before `$1` in the substitution. Since the directory prefix is removed from the captured pattern. If this was directly in your server config then you would not need this.

The above *conditions* can be combined into one, if you want:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|secure)\. [NC]
```

And then, to force SSL on the `secure` subdomain, add the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secure\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: By all rights this should work, and it does work on a test site I set up.  It just doesn't work on production which leads me to think something else is going on.  The secure subdomain part is not working for me, although it does assign it HTTPS.

Comment: Are you saying the `secure` subdomain is not being excluded in the first ruleset? But the 2nd ruleset is successfully redirecting the `secure` subdomain to `HTTPS`? This sounds like it could be a caching issue - have you cleared your browser (and any intermediary) caches? 301 redirects are cached by the browser, so if you had previously accessed the `secure` subdomain using your original ruleset then you would have been redirected and this redirect would have been cached. It is often best to test with 302 (temporary) redirects for this reason - which should not be cached.

Comment: What is happening, is that it loads up the https://secure.domain.com address just fine for a half of a second and then redirects to https://www.domain.com.  The site is also a Wordpress Multisite hosted on Amazon AWS with elasticache, s3 and OpsWorks all in play, which complicates things immensely.  So while your solution is right, there is something else preventing it from working.

Comment: Figured out the problem.  This is a wordpress multisite that was installed without subdomains and the wp-config.php file is redirecting the subdomain to the main www url because it has subdomain support disabled in wp-config.